# How to secure code in iPhone application by preventing decompiling

Tags: ios, wcf, security

The WCF service Authentication info in my iPhone application code, is seen after decompiling.
Can decompiling be prevented? Otherwise, is it possible to restrict other applications to access the service 
with this authentication info.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: andre dekompilerer applikasjonen min og bruker 'min' tilgangs kode til aa faa adgang til denne servicen. det jeg lurer paa her er hvordan jeg kan forhindre dette. trenger virkelig hjelp her..

Comment: Jeg svarer deg på engelsk siden dette er en internasjonal side: It isn't possible to prevent decompilation. The best you can do is to obscure the authentication info, but if someone really wants it, they will get it (like scannig the web requests using a proxy). If you have problems with abuse of your web service, you might want to concider redesigning your authentication method, but as I said. That's too broad for this site.

Comment: our authentication info is encrypted in code but it can still be used because  the service accepts encryted parameters. What do you recommend in this case.